# Gettting an error while importing solution from dynamic crm online 2013 to crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

So here is my problem,
I am trying to import the solution from crm 2013 online version to crm 2011 and while doing it, it throws an error message

> The import file is invalid. XSD validation failed with the following error: 'The element 'attribute' has invalid child element 'IntroducedVersion'.
>   List of possible elements expected:
>   'LookupBrowse, MaxValue, ReferencedEntityObjectTypeCode,
>   CanModifySearchSettings, MaxLength, CanModifyAdditionalSettings,
>   XmlAbbreviation, AggregateOf, YomiOf, AttributeOf, AccuracySource,
>   displaynames, Descriptions, Length, Accuracy, LinkedAttribute,
>   CalculationOf, LookupTypes, CanModifyFieldLevelSecuritySettings,
>   LookupStyle, Format, MinValue, OptionSetName,
>   CanModifyRequirementLevelSettings, AppDefaultValue, optionset,
>   IsRenameable, IsCustomizable'.

This solution was first created in crm 2011 and then got upgraded to crm 2013 due to which when I try to bring it back to crm 2011, it is giving me this error message.

Please help me out to work with this issue.

Comment: What are the contents of the solution?  Plugins, entities, or only a bunch of web resources?

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer: You can't.

Long Answer: As the error message pointed out the `XSD` validation failed. This means that CRM 2011 validates the xml contained inside the solution with its schema. CRM 2013 introduced several changes in forms and components (and accordingly its validation scheda), so the solutions are not backward compatible.

You can try to manually adapt the xml solution to a CRM 2011 xml file, but I don't know if you can succeed and probably it's easier to replicate the customization inside the CRM 2011 environment.

Comment: You talked about doing it manually. I am not an expert in this so it will be a little difficult but can you please elaborate as to how can it be done manually.

Comment: If you are not an expert then manually adapting the xml is pretty much out of the question. The other option that Guido mentioned, manually re-do all the customizations in 2011, might be the way to go.

Comment: is there a way, i can manually add the files of the solution one by one?

Comment: You could add one component to a new solution and export that.